# How to reset all settings and get back initial blender setings?

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, customization

I did some changes in user preferences, but I forgot that changes and where I did them. How to I get back the initial blender settings?

Answer (score 5):

In a 3D ViewPort, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, then enter 'load factory'. You'll see an operator called 'load factory settings'.

[image: load factory]

When you execute that, you get the Default Scene back, and the settings as well. Remember to save your user settings now by going to the User Preferences, and hit 'Save User Settings', as well as hitting <kbd>Ctrl + U</kbd> in the 3D Viewport and save the startup file.

Comment: great! could you please mark my answer as the answer to your question? Thank you!